# How to move a WordPress multisite?

Tags: multisite

I have a WP multisite installation like this:

1. www.mysite.com
2. www.mysite.com/anothersite

Now, I'd like to move www.mysite.com/anothersite to be www.mysite.com.
Is it possible?

Comment: Is `www.mysite.com` the first site in your multisite setup?

Comment: @Zypher yes www.mysite.com is the first site in my multisite setup

Comment: So you did a subdirectory site and not a subdomain site?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes it's a subdirectory site

Comment: If this is possible, it will have to be done within WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to export `www.mysite.com/anothersite` to a WXR file using **Tools » Export** in your WordPress backend -- `www.mysite.com/anothersite/wp-admin`.  Then you can go to `www.mysite.com/wp-admin`, remove the existing content (delete your existing posts / pages / etc -- export them first if you want/need a backup) and then use **Tools » Import** to import the WXR file.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, all you need to do is change your web server's configuration to point `www.mysite.com` to the folder where `www.mysite.com/anothersite` resides.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if I do this what will happen to the "network of sites" i created with [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: In Multisite, `/anothersite` doesn't have a folder on the server; it's a fiction maintained by WordPress rather than an actual location.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, change the `DocumentRoot` of mysite.com so that points to the directory where are stored the files of anothersite, and restart the webserver.

Comment: In Multisite, `/anothersite` doesn't have a directory.